# Docker not starting with 'Fatal Error - failed to run backend processes'

Tags: docker

I have been trying to build an image from Mac terminal `sudo DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .` for a Stable Diffusion API but couldn't get it to work no matter what I tried.

I ended up uninstalling Docker with `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/uninstall` and then deleting the Docker app from my Applications folder.

I restarted, downloaded a new Docker.img from the Docker website and tried to reinstall it.

Now I'm getting:

```
Fatal Error

supervising tasks: task failed: shutdown with exit code 1: com.docker.build with pid: 1354

failed to run backend processes
```

- or -

```
Fatal Error

supervising tasks: task failed: shutdown with exit code 1: com.docker.build with pid: 1456

failed to run backend processes
```

Also, under System Settings -> General -> Login items -> Allow in background I have 3 versions of Docker:

Docker (1 item)
Docker (1 item: 1 item affects all users)
Docker Inc (1 item: 1 item affects all users)

I have tried having them all off/ all on/ each on, etc, etc but nothing works.

I've reinstalled twice.

I've reset factory defaults twice.

I've gone to forums.docker.com looking for answers, nothing.

I was expecting that reinstalling Docker would allow me to finally build that Docker image that I wanted to build but the install itself hasn't worked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be an error of permission on the folder `<HOME>/.docker/buildx`.

Try to remove the folder with:

```
sudo rm -rf <HOME>/.docker/buildx
```

and relaunch Docker Desktop.

The folder `buildx` will be re-created with the right permissions.